# Setting text for TextView not working properly

Tags: java, android, textview

When I Set Text in `TextView`, its text changes after going to `correctCondition()` method; but I want to change text before going to `correctCondition()`.
so That `TextView` will change when I click button, and then further operations run.

I want to play sound "one" and display text "1" at the same time

Here I add some code in

```
image1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (mClicked == false) {
                mClicked = true;
                count = count + 1;
                numberWrite.setText("" + count);
                one();
                correctCondition();

            }  
        }
    });




private void one() {

        Thread tr = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

        AssetFileDescriptor one;
        try {
            one = mActivity.getAssets().openFd(
                    "counting/one.mp3");

        MediaPlayer counting = new MediaPlayer();


            counting.setDataSource(one.getFileDescriptor(),
                    one.getStartOffset(), one.getLength());
            one.close();
            counting.prepare();
            counting.setVolume(1f, 1f);
            counting.start();

            counting.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                }
            });





        } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    });

        tr.start();
}

public void playCorrectBeep() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MediaPlayer correctMp = new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor correct = mContext.getAssets().openFd(
                        "correct.mp3");
                correctMp.setDataSource(correct.getFileDescriptor(),
                correct.getStartOffset(),correct.getLength());

                correct.close();
                correctMp.prepare();
                correctMp.start();
                correctMp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.release();
                            }
                        });
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    t.start();

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: if I try to set text before if condition then how should add updated count in textview

Comment: yeah i saw that, try pausing the thread for a while then if you want to show updated textView

Answer (score 1):

**Your switch needs a "break"**, do it like this:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.imageView1:

        if (mClicked == false) {
            mClicked = true;
            count = count + 1;                    
            numberWrite.setText(""+ count);  
            toast.cancel();

            soundManager.one();
            correctCondition();
        }

     break; // add this line
 }
```

Furthermore, **you should not let your correctCondition() method run on the UI-Thread.** Instead, let your SoundManager.one(); run in a separate Thread.

```
public void one() {

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable) {

        public void run() {

          counting = new MediaPlayer();
          try {

            counting.setDataSource(one.getFileDescriptor(), one.getStartOffset(), one.getLength());
            one.close();
            counting.prepare();
            counting.setVolume(1f, 1f);
            counting.start();

            counting.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                   }
            });

         } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
         }
       }
     };
     t.start();
}
```

Comment: I try to use same code , but soundManager.One(); play before but text set late

I remove Uithread from correctCondition()

Comment: See my updated answer and put the one() method in a thread, maybe it works then. Does the text "wait" to be set until one(); has been executed?

Comment: I try to change the whole code , now I edit my code again and use sound methods in same activity but having same result.

When I set wait then congrats sound and one sound as well as text all run on same time :(